# Create a server-less reminder system

Tags: architecture, system-design

I want to create an application in which the users want to be notified about a message at any point in time. For e.g. If a user asks that reminds me something on the 1st of every month.

Do I have to create a separate application that will work as a ticker, check the time, retrieve users who have set up a reminder at this time and send them a notification? Is there any other fashion in which I could use services in AWS like SNS and some lambda which will do this operation in a serverless manner and I would just have to write a lambda function that will just send the notification and AWS will automatically trigger my lambda at all the timestamps when the user's reminders are set?

There will be many users of this application.

Answer (score 0):

Step function with dynamic wait seems to be the perfect solution here. Here is the official reference for it.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html

Comment: How to cancel this reminder from the outside step function? If I set a reminder and then change my mind, how to cancel it?

Comment: You can save the cancellation token and then call a method to stop execution of state machine. It's part of the aws sdk.